# Possible to Partition Analytics into DEBUG and RELEASE?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, configuration

I have been using Google Analytics since 2010, and am being forced to migrate to Firebase. Something I have always done and is critical to me is have 2 versions of the app on the developer console. 1 for `DEBUG` and 1 for `RELEASE`. I have set preprocessor flags and configuration flags in place to determine when to send logging data to one or another. Now that Firebase requires that the key be present in a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file (and no longer configured via code) I am wondering how I would go about doing what I previously had done.

Previously I would use the following:

```
if (LIVE_RELEASE && !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) {
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:UA_NUM_LIVE];
} else {
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:UA_NUM_BETA];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two plist files and configure using the appropriate file as per mode

```
if (LIVE_RELEASE && !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR) {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info_Dev" ofType:@"plist"];
    FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
} else {
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GoogleService-Info_Prod" ofType:@"plist"];
    FIROptions *options = [[FIROptions alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [FIRApp configureWithOptions:options];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation is always to use separate Firebase projects to isolate the data from each app that runs in a different environment.  For apps that don't share data at all, putting them in the same project leads to complications.

Comment: Right, so I should follow what [Mitesh Prajapati's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58021207/347339) proposes?

Comment: You can do whatever you want to configure your app to point to different projects.  I don't think there is just one implementation path for that.  Whatever you think is best.

Comment: If there is another method of doing this that you are aware of that hasn't been presented as an answer already could you please post it?